# Query across the rows in dataframe 'Pandas'

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe as mentioned below, How can I get the "Categories" which is contributing at-least 30% to overall business across different "Organization". I tried below query, but didn't work.

```
Organization_category_df = df.loc[(df['Year 2014-15']) >= 0.3 * (df['Category'] == 'Total Business')]
```

[image]

**My bad I'm not able to add a table, anyways I created a html table at-least that should be helpful in copying the data.**

```html
<table>
<tr>
    <th>Year 2014-15</th>
    <th>Category</th>
    <th>Organization</th>
</tr>
 <tr>
    <td>35000</td>
    <td>laptop</td>
    <td>xyz</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>25000</td>
    <td>tablet</td>
    <td>xyz</td>
  </tr> 
   <tr>
    <td>40000</td>
    <td>mobile</td>
    <td>xyz</td>
  </tr>
   <tr>
    <td>100000</td>
    <td>Total Business</td>
    <td>xyz</td>
  </tr>
<tr>
    <td>23000</td>
    <td>laptop</td>
    <td>pqr</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>10000</td>
    <td>tablet</td>
    <td>pqr</td>
  </tr> 
   <tr>
    <td>15000</td>
    <td>mobile</td>
    <td>pqr</td>
  </tr>
   <tr>
    <td>48000</td>
    <td>Total Business</td>
    <td>pqr</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: [please do not post images of data](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question) . repost as text please

Comment: My bad I'm not able to add a table, anyways I created a html table at-least that should be helpful in copying the data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IIUC, the rows with sub-totals ("Total Business") make things complicated. Easy to create a [`boolean mask`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#boolean-indexing) to filter these out, then you can use [`groupby.transform`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.transform.html) to filter your `DataFrame`.

If needed, you can reinsert the "Total Business" rows with [`pandas.concat`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.concat.html) and [`sort_index`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.sort_index.html):

```
mask = df['Category'].eq('Total Business')

df_filtered = df[~mask]
df_filtered = df_filtered[df_filtered.groupby('Organization')['Year 2014-15'].transform(lambda x: x / x.sum()).ge(0.3)]
print(df_filtered)
```

[out]

```
   Year 2014-15 Category Organization
0         35000   laptop          xyz
2         40000   mobile          xyz
4         23000   laptop          pqr
6         15000   mobile          pqr
```

And with "Total Business" re-added:

```
df_filtered = pd.concat([df_filtered, df[mask]]).sort_index()
```

[out]

```
   Year 2014-15        Category Organization
0         35000          laptop          xyz
2         40000          mobile          xyz
3        100000  Total Business          xyz
4         23000          laptop          pqr
6         15000          mobile          pqr
7         48000  Total Business          pqr
```

Comment: can I know where are you considering the "Total Business" in the code "df_filtered = df_filtered[df_filtered.groupby('Organization')['Year 2014-15'].transform(lambda x: x / x.sum()).ge(0.3)]"

Comment: yes, in `transform` method `x.sum()` is the total summed "Year 2014-15" for each Organization. So calculates to `100000` for `'xyz'` and `48000` for `'pqr'`

Answer (score 0):

Here, df.groupby('category')['Year 2014-15'].sum() would sum the business across organization per category. You can calculate the val which would constitute 30% of overall business and whole command would give you category which constitute more than val

There is misclarity on 30% business as overall or 30% business per organization which will decide val value

```
(df['category'].unique())[df.groupby('category')['Year 2014-15'].sum() > val ]
```